# Change in .env file not reflecting in Docker container

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

The question is related to a Laravel project run in a Docker container, but is applicable for any kind of project and any kind of container since the .env files are common on all platforms.

After changing a variable value in an `.env` file, the project that is run inside a docker container doesn't see the change and still runs with previous values. In Laravel, there are commands to clear the cached config, but that doesn't seem to change the values inside the running container. Even running docker-compose with `--force-recreate` flag doesn't update the containers .env values. So basically, none of the following work:

`docker exec -it container_name php artisan config:clear`
`docker exec -it container_name php artisan cache:clear`
`docker-compose run --build --force-recreate`

What is the correct way to update environment variable's value in a running Docker container?

Answer (score 1):

If you do the following you should see changes in the container:

Create a .env file with some content.

Then create this docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  tmp:
    image: alpine
    container_name: SomeContainer
    volumes:
      - ./.env:/root/.env:rw
    command: ["sleep", "300d"]
```

After starting it with

```sh
docker-compose up -d
```

And changing the .env file, changes should immediately be reflected in the Container.